# Cannot see PostgreSQL-tables in QGIS as a 'non' super user

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have established a connection between QGIS and PostgreSQL. As long as the active user has the 'Super User'check-box enabled, all works well. From the moment I disable it only the Schema's remain visible. The layers are gone.
I searched the Internet but can't find any solution.

PostgreSQL 11 /
PostGIS 2.5 /
QGIS 3.4.1 /
Windows 10 (home edition)

Comment: I have the same problem still. Give Grant for user, but QGIS don`t whant to connect with postgres

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to explicitly grant privileges to the user:

```sql
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA mySchema TO myUser;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON  mySchema.myTable TO myUser;
```

Comment: Or alternatively to a role to which the user belongs.